# Extracción de datos de varias columnas y filas para generar nueva columna de un dataframe Pandas en Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Utilizando Python con pandas, en un dataframe se tienen datos de 5 columnas, con las que se tiene que crear una nueva columna. Las columnas se resumen en:

1. el índice;
2. los nombres de “clientes”, habiendo varias filas de un mismo cliente;
3. la “fecha actual”, entendiendo que cada cliente va a tener diferentes filas con fechas distintas, pero los demás clientes también tienen otras filas distintas con fechas iguales;
4. el “monto actual”;
5. la “fecha futura”, que no necesariamente van a ser las mismas para todos los clientes y;
6. el “monto estimado” es la columna que se busca crear.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se busca es crear una nueva sexta columna de “MONTO ESTIMADO”, de forma que de cada cliente se itere por la columna de “FECHA FUTURA”, de manera que con el dato de esa fecha de la iteración, se busque esa misma fecha en la columna de “FECHA ACTUAL” pero sólo del actual cliente (del de la fila que se está iterando). La fecha que se va a buscar en la columna de “FECHA ACTUAL” que va a estar en otra fila posterior, no va a ser la de la siguiente fila como se ve en el cuadro, será bastante posterior.
Una vez encontrada la “FECHA ACTUAL” en alguna fila posterior, se debe copiar el “MONTO ACTUAL” presente en esa fila posterior a la nueva columna de “MONTO ESTIMADO” pero en la fila donde se ha iterado la “FECHA FUTURA”, y así sucesivamente.

A su vez, puede ser que no se encuentre una fecha de “FECHA FUTURA” igual en la columna de “FECHA ACTUAL”, por lo que de darse esa situación se tendría que restar 1 día, o 2 o 3 días a esa fecha iterada de “FECHA FUTURA” hasta encontrar una similar en la columna de “FECHA ACTUAL”. (Estos si que no he podido hacerlo con “if” o “elif”, no sé por dónde ir). También, no se tienen todas las fechas en la columna “FECHA FUTURA”, por lo que se observan NaT, de forma que cuando se llegue a un “CLIENTE” con “FECHA FUTURA” inexistente, se deberá pasar a iterar al siguiente “CLIENTE” y de ser posible borrar esa fila.

Por ejemplo, de la columna “FECHA FUTURA” del dato o fecha “2022-03-20” del cliente AAA en la fila 0, se busca esa misma fecha en la columna “FECHA ACTUAL” pero sólo en las filas del cliente AAA. De esta forma, se encuentra esa fecha en la fila 1 columna “FECHA ACTUAL”, por lo que se copia el “MONTO ACTUAL” de la fila 1 en la columna “MONTO ESTIMADO” de la fila 0, y así sucesivamente.

He tratado de realizarlo con bucles for y por otros medios, pero no pude conseguirlo. Si alguien me puede ayudar a resolver este problema le quedaría muy agradecido. Gracias de antemano y saludos.
Copio el código con el que trabajé pero sin resultados, intentando con un bucle que se itere sobre el índice, para que con el mismo, se genere una variable que obtenga el valor de la fila del índice de la columna “FECHA FUTURA” . De igual forma, se genera otra variable pero para “CLEINTES”.
Con ello, se aplica un filtro para buscar con las variables obtenidas, la “FECHA ACTUAL” igual a la “FECHA FUTURA”, pero del mismo cliente, de forma que al obtener el índice de donde está la “FECHA ACTUAL” buscada, después se copia el “MONTO ACTUAL” relacionado a ese nuevo índice, originalmente intenté creando una lista, para luego adjuntar esta lista como la columna en el dataframe, pero me parece que se podría hacerlo directamente sin generar una nueva llista.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
#from datetime import datetime
#from datetime import date
#from datetime import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'CLIENTES':['AAA','AAA','AAA','BBB','BBB','BBB','CCC','CCC','CCC'],
                   'FECHA_ACTUAL':['2022-01-10','2022-03-20','2022-08-14','2022-01-10','2022-03-20','2022-08-14','2022-01-10','2022-03-20','2022-08-14'],
                   'MONTO_ACTUAL':[50,30,60,130,250,500,38,20,12],
                   'FECHA_FUTURA':['2022-03-20','2022-08-14', np.nan,'2022-03-20','2022-07-02',np.nan,'2022-04-07','2022-09-09',np.nan],
                   'MONTO_ESTIMADO':[30,60,np.nan,250,400,np.nan,40,30,np.nan]})


df['FECHA_ACTUAL'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA_ACTUAL'], format='%Y-%m-%d') #Se convierte Fecha_asctual en formato datetime, ya que se necesitará hacer cálculos de fechas.
df['FECHA_FUTURA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA_FUTURA'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

#Se inserta una columna con un índice numérico para que posteriormente sea más facil hacer la iteración
df['INDICE']=np.arange(len(df))
df=df.reindex(columns=['INDICE','CLIENTES','FECHA_ACTUAL','MONTO_ACTUAL','FECHA_FUTURA','MONTO_ESTIMADO'])
print(df)
```

Se intenta generar el bucle mencionado:

```
lista = []

for i in df.INDICE:
    x1 = df.at[i, "FECHA_FUTURA"]
    y1 = df.at[i, "CLIENTES"]
    filtro0 = df[(df['FECHA_ACTUAL'] == x1) & (df['CLIENTES'] == y1)]     
    filtro1 = filtro0.INDICE
    df.loc[i,'MONTO_ESTIMADO'] = df.loc[filtro1,'MONTO_ACTUAL']
lista
```

Comment: Buen día, cuando la fecha no existe mencionas que hay que buscar 1, 2 ó 3 días anteriores a la fecha, ¿Cuál sería el número máximo de días que se tiene que buscar hacia atrás cuando no se encuentra la fecha? Aparte, ¿Qué sucedería en caso de que la fecha futura no se encuentre en la fecha actual y al buscar, digamos 2 días hacia atrás sea la misma fila donde está la fecha futura, igual se copia el monto?

Comment: Buenas. El número máximo de días hacia atrás sería de 3, pero primero intentando 1, si no lo encuentra 2 días y sino 3 días. Para la data con la que estoy trabajando, si se encontraría la fecha futura en la columna de fecha actual, ya que la fecha futura es un resultado de una suma de la fecha actual. Lo que si podría pasar es que ya no haya una fecha futura, en ese caso ya se borraría la fila y se pasaría al indice siguiente de otro cliente. Muchas gracias y saludos

Comment: Ok, entendido ¿Y la segunda pregunta?

Comment: En caso de que con la fecha futura no se encuentre la fecha actual retrocediendo 1,2 o 3 días, se debería borrar esa línea o poner NaN. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) para lograrlo. Ajústate el cinturón de seguridad que la lectura es extensa (Porque es un problema complicado) y nos vamos rápido.

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces `apply` podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Utilizando el siguiente `dataframe` como referencia:

**Nota:** Agregué una fila más para el cliente "BBB" donde `FECHA_ACTUAL` fuera un día antes que la `FECHA_FUTURA` para comprobar que funciona correctamente (Fila con índice 5).

```
  CLIENTES FECHA_ACTUAL  MONTO_ACTUAL FECHA_FUTURA
0      AAA   2022-01-10            50   2022-03-20
1      AAA   2022-03-20            30   2022-08-14
2      AAA   2022-08-14            60          NaT
3      BBB   2022-01-10           130   2022-03-20
4      BBB   2022-03-20           250   2022-07-02
5      BBB   2022-07-01           500          NaT
6      BBB   2022-08-14           500          NaT
7      CCC   2022-01-10            38   2022-04-07
8      CCC   2022-03-20            20   2022-09-09
9      CCC   2022-08-14            12          NaT
```

Lo que vamos a hacer primero crear una copia del `dataframe` y a esa copia agregarle 3 columnas que serán la `FECHA_ACTUAL` pero desfasada 1, 2 y 3 días.

```
# Copiar el dataframe
df_copy = df.copy()

# Creamos columnas para 1, 2 y 3 días posteriores a FECHA_ACTUAL
df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL_1'] = df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL'] + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL_2'] = df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL'] + pd.DateOffset(days=2)
df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL_3'] = df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL'] + pd.DateOffset(days=3)
```

Luego utilizamos `merge` utilizando las columnas de `FECHA_FUTURA` y `CLIENTES` de `df_copy` como referencia y vamos a asignar los valores de las demás columnas donde `FECHA_ACTUAL` y `CLIENTES` coincidan con nuestra referencia:

```
# Merge usando 'FECHA_FUTURA' donde sea igual a 'FECHA_ACTUAL' y el mismo valor en 'CLIENTES'
# Esta es para cuando FECHA_FUTURA es igual a FECHA_ACTUAL, utilizamos el sufijo "_0"
merged_df = df_copy.merge(df_copy, left_on=['FECHA_FUTURA','CLIENTES'], right_on=['FECHA_ACTUAL','CLIENTES'], how='left',suffixes=('', '_0'))
```

Creamos el nuevo `dataframe` `merged_df` ya que el proceso va a crear muchas columnas que no vamos a necesitar y no queremos generar "basura" en nuestro `dataframe` original.

La línea anterior (Si la imprimes) habrá generado un montón de columnas:

```
Index(['CLIENTES', 'FECHA_ACTUAL', 'MONTO_ACTUAL', 'FECHA_FUTURA',
       'MONTO_ESTIMADO', 'FECHA_ACTUAL_1', 'FECHA_ACTUAL_2', 'FECHA_ACTUAL_3',
       'FECHA_ACTUAL_0', 'MONTO_ACTUAL_0', 'FECHA_FUTURA_0',
       'MONTO_ESTIMADO_0', 'FECHA_ACTUAL_1_0', 'FECHA_ACTUAL_2_0',
       'FECHA_ACTUAL_3_0'],
      dtype='object')
```

Todas las que tienen sufijo `_0` fueron creadas con el `merge` anterior, pero de todas esas la única que nos interesa es `MONTO_ACTUAL_0` que será el valor de `MONTO_ACTUAL` donde `FECHA_ACTUAL` coincidió con `FECHA_FUTURA` y tienen el mismo cliente.

Para obtener los valores de la fecha desfasada 1, 2 y 3 días también utilizamos `merge` pero asignamos sufijos `_1`, `_2` y `_3` respectivamente. Voy a omitir mostrar todas las columnas que se crean pero te recomiendo utilizar `print(merged_df.columns)` después de cada `merge` para que veas lo que está sucediendo con el `dataframe`.

```
# Esta es para cuando FECHA_FUTURA es igual a FECHA_ACTUAL + 1 día, utilizamos el sufijo "_1"
merged_df = merged_df.merge(df_copy, left_on=['FECHA_FUTURA','CLIENTES'], right_on=['FECHA_ACTUAL_1','CLIENTES'], how='left',suffixes=('', '_1'))

# Esta es para cuando FECHA_FUTURA es igual a FECHA_ACTUAL + 2 días, utilizamos el sufijo "_2"
merged_df = merged_df.merge(df_copy, left_on=['FECHA_FUTURA','CLIENTES'], right_on=['FECHA_ACTUAL_2','CLIENTES'], how='left',suffixes=('', '_2'))

# Esta es para cuando FECHA_FUTURA es igual a FECHA_ACTUAL + 3 días, utilizamos el sufijo "_3"
merged_df = merged_df.merge(df_copy, left_on=['FECHA_FUTURA','CLIENTES'], right_on=['FECHA_ACTUAL_3','CLIENTES'], how='left',suffixes=('', '_3'))
```

Ya que pudimos fusionar y obtener los montos de los días 0, 1, 2 y 3 entonces procedemos a crear la serie de valores que utilizaremos para crear la nueva columna.

En primer lugar nos interesa el `MONTO_ACTUAL` del día 0:

```
# Seleccionamos el valor de día 0, es decir, cuando FECHA_FUTURA == FECHA_ACTUAL
value = merged_df.MONTO_ACTUAL_0
```

Luego vamos a rellenar los valores vacíos de esta serie con los valores de `MONTO_ACTUAL` de los días siguientes, si existieran:

```
# Rellenamos los valores vacíos con FECHA_FUTURA == FECHA_ACTUAL + n
# Donde n va de 1-3 respectivamente
# Es decir, rellena únicamente si está vacío para no sobreescribir datos
value = value.fillna(merged_df.MONTO_ACTUAL_1)
value = value.fillna(merged_df.MONTO_ACTUAL_2)
value = value.fillna(merged_df.MONTO_ACTUAL_3)
```

Por último, rellenamos los valores vacíos con `NaN`

```
value = value.fillna(np.nan)
```

Y por fin podemos asignar estos valores a una nueva columna `MONTO_ESTIMADO`

```
df['MONTO_ESTIMADO'] = value
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'CLIENTES':['AAA','AAA','AAA','BBB','BBB','BBB','BBB','CCC','CCC','CCC'],
                   'FECHA_ACTUAL':['2022-01-10','2022-03-20','2022-08-14','2022-01-10','2022-03-20','2022-07-01','2022-08-14','2022-01-10','2022-03-20','2022-08-14'],
                   'MONTO_ACTUAL':[50,30,60,130,250,500,500,38,20,12],
                   'FECHA_FUTURA':['2022-03-20','2022-08-14', np.nan,'2022-03-20','2022-07-02',np.nan,np.nan,'2022-04-07','2022-09-09',np.nan]})

# Convertimos a fechas
df['FECHA_ACTUAL'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA_ACTUAL'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['FECHA_FUTURA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA_FUTURA'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# Copiar el dataframe
df_copy = df.copy()

# Creamos columnas para 1, 2 y 3 días posteriores a FECHA_ACTUAL
df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL_1'] = df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL'] + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL_2'] = df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL'] + pd.DateOffset(days=2)
df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL_3'] = df_copy['FECHA_ACTUAL'] + pd.DateOffset(days=3)

# Merge usando 'FECHA_FUTURA' donde sea igual a 'FECHA_ACTUAL' y el mismo valor en 'CLIENTES'
# Esta es para cuando FECHA_FUTURA es igual a FECHA_ACTUAL, utilizamos el sufijo "_0"
merged_df = df_copy.merge(df_copy, left_on=['FECHA_FUTURA','CLIENTES'], right_on=['FECHA_ACTUAL','CLIENTES'], how='left',suffixes=('', '_0'))

# Esta es para cuando FECHA_FUTURA es igual a FECHA_ACTUAL + 1 día, utilizamos el sufijo "_1"
merged_df = merged_df.merge(df_copy, left_on=['FECHA_FUTURA','CLIENTES'], right_on=['FECHA_ACTUAL_1','CLIENTES'], how='left',suffixes=('', '_1'))

# Esta es para cuando FECHA_FUTURA es igual a FECHA_ACTUAL + 2 días, utilizamos el sufijo "_2"
merged_df = merged_df.merge(df_copy, left_on=['FECHA_FUTURA','CLIENTES'], right_on=['FECHA_ACTUAL_2','CLIENTES'], how='left',suffixes=('', '_2'))

# Esta es para cuando FECHA_FUTURA es igual a FECHA_ACTUAL + 3 días, utilizamos el sufijo "_3"
merged_df = merged_df.merge(df_copy, left_on=['FECHA_FUTURA','CLIENTES'], right_on=['FECHA_ACTUAL_3','CLIENTES'], how='left',suffixes=('', '_3'))

# Seleccionamos el valor de día 0, es decir, cuando FECHA_FUTURA == FECHA_ACTUAL
value = merged_df.MONTO_ACTUAL_0

# Rellenamos los valores vacíos con FECHA_FUTURA == FECHA_ACTUAL + n
# Donde n va de 1-3 respectivamente
# Es decir, rellena únicamente si está vacío para no sobreescribir datos
value = value.fillna(merged_df.MONTO_ACTUAL_1)
value = value.fillna(merged_df.MONTO_ACTUAL_2)
value = value.fillna(merged_df.MONTO_ACTUAL_3)

# Rellenar los datos faltantes con NaN
value = value.fillna(np.nan)

# Asignamos los valores obtenidos a la nueva columna
df['MONTO_ESTIMADO'] = value

print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
  CLIENTES FECHA_ACTUAL  MONTO_ACTUAL FECHA_FUTURA  MONTO_ESTIMADO
0      AAA   2022-01-10            50   2022-03-20            30.0
1      AAA   2022-03-20            30   2022-08-14            60.0
2      AAA   2022-08-14            60          NaT             NaN
3      BBB   2022-01-10           130   2022-03-20           250.0
4      BBB   2022-03-20           250   2022-07-02           500.0
5      BBB   2022-07-01           500          NaT             NaN
6      BBB   2022-08-14           500          NaT             NaN
7      CCC   2022-01-10            38   2022-04-07             NaN
8      CCC   2022-03-20            20   2022-09-09             NaN
9      CCC   2022-08-14            12          NaT             NaN
```

**Nota adicional:** Es posible que yo haya comprendido mal si deseas comparar días al futuro o al pasado de `FECHA_ACTUAL` si en el ejemplo mostré la dirección opuesta a lo que deseas puedes modificarlo cambiando el signo de las líneas donde se crean las nuevas columnas para la fecha desfasada, por ejemplo podrías poner `pd.DateOffset(days=-1)`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por las recomendaciones y la solución del problema, estuve un buen tiempo sin poder avanzar. Lo iré implementando. Saludos

Comment: La solución tampoco estuvo tan fácil, ya casi te voy a cobrar el día xD